# How to convert a string to TimeSpan in format "HH:mm:ss"

Tags: c#

In my code i have this:

```
string myString;
TimeSpan? myTimeSpan;

myString = myTimeSpan.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

I got the error no overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments.

I want convert TimeSpan to string in format HH:mm:ss.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings

Comment: This should throw a NullReferenceException, anyway. But if the compiler says this, then something else is very very off, too. You are sure, that's a [`System.TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-6.0), not a custom class by the same name? Could you add a little more context of your code? Because there _is_ such an overload.

Comment: @Fildor Is a TimeSpan? yes

Comment: ^^ [TimeSpan.ToString(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-timespan-tostring(system-string)) exists, so there must be something else wrong here.

Comment: @Fildor - they've now inserted a `?` so they're working with a `Nullable<TimeSpan>` with no such overload.

Comment: Ahhhh, haha.... wait. It's a `TimeSpan?` ? - Different story, then.

Comment: As you have a nullable instance, then you need something like myString.Value.ToString(...); (You would need to check for null!!)

Comment: @PaulF **myTimeSpan**.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss");, but yes.

Comment: Yes it's a TimeSpan. I need put myTimeSpan.Value.ToString.....

It's working now :) 

Thanks @Fildor

Comment: @Marco: _"Yes it's a TimeSpan"_ - No it's not. As Damien said: it's a `Nullable<TimeSpan>`. Which has a `Value` Property, which gives you the TimeSpan (if the nullable has a value at all).

Comment: @Marco: Instead of myTimeSpane.Value.ToString("...") which needs a check for null, an alternative would be myTimeSpane.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("...") - if null you would get "00:00:00" as the output.

Comment: Maybe `myString = myTimeSpan?.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss");` using the null-safe `?.` access. That will  give a `null` string if `myTimeSpan` has no `.Value`. Another option, also safe with null, is `myString = $"{myTimeSpan:hh':'mm':'ss}";` which will give `""` if there is no time span.

Answer (score 2):

First problem: you use a `Nullable<TimeSpan>`, so you need to use it's `Value` property,

---

[`TimeSpan.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-timespan-tostring(system-string)) does not support all format strings that [`DateTime.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-6.0) supports.

You need to escape the `:`:

```
Console.Write(System.DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss"));
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uIMqW0

Read: [Custom TimeSpan format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings)